# Nested .SelectMany statements in C# / LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have the below code which works perfectly fine:

```
return from fa in [...]
where fa.Flows.Any()
from f in fa.Flows
select new Flow(f.Id, f.DealingDate, f.NetCashUsd, fa.Account);
```

As you can see, I need Account from fa deeper down in the second select.

However I'm required to use ".Selects" instead, and this (equivalent I thought) does not work:

```
return [...]
.Where(fa => fa.Flows.Any())
.SelectMany(fa => fa.Flows)
.Select(f => new Flow(f.Id, f.DealingDate, f.NetCashUsd, fa.Account));
```

The issue here is obvious, the second .Select doesn't "know" the fa stuff anymore so can't get to Account.

(As you can probably tell by now, an "fa" has one Account and multiple Flows, and I want to turn them into "Flow"s which all have the Account assigned to them as well.)

How can I solve this using only the "." statements? I looked into different GroupBys as well but couldn't make them work either.

Thank you!

Comment: Why in the 2nd method you are using Select Many?  Select many only works on a table (two dimensional array).  You only have a one dimensional array so you cannot use SelectMany.

Comment: @jdweng Clearly `Flows` is a collection and that is what the OP is flattening with `SelectMany`.

Comment: Just curious, but what exactly requires you to use method syntax over query syntax?

Comment: Correct juharr - and that just seems to be the standard here. Worst case it's possible, but I'm being told there should be a way to achieve the same using .Selects and .GroupBys?

Comment: @Oli Yes, all query syntax is ultimately compiled into the methods.  But using one over the other is more about style and readability than functionality.

Comment: juharr : It is a collection which is a one dimensional array.  Not two dimensions.  A colection is List<>, while a two dimensional array is List<List<>>.  Select many you need a two dimensional array.

Comment: @jdweng No the type returned by the lambda just needs to be a collection.  I think you're confusing this with the type that it's called on.  So in this case `SelectMany` is called on a collection that contains a collection called `Flows`.  That's your 2 dimensions.

Comment: I am not wrong.  You cannot take a List<>: object and perform SelectMany!!!  If you have an array int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6} what do you get if you perform a SelectMany()?

Answer (score 4):

An [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `SelectMany` uses an extra argument (result selector) in which you can define the returned objects. In this result selector you have access to both source item and sub item:

```
[....]
.SelectMany(fa => fa.Flows, (fa,f)=> new Flow(f.Id, f.DealingDate, f.NetCashUsd, fa.Account));
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent would be to create an intermediate anonymous type to hold both objects.

```
return [...]
    .SelectMany(fa => fa.Flows.Select(f => new { f, fa}))
    .Select(x => new Flow(x.f.Id, x.f.DealingDate, x.f.NetCashUsd, x.fa.Account));
```

Also you don't need the `Where` since an empty `Flows` will just result in no selected items.